# Why LinkedIn API works fine for company but gives error 403 for a person set as admin on this company?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'd like to get company feed and statistics and the same for the boss of the company.
I managed to get what I want for the company account but not for the person.

I'll try to expose what I've done so far....
I have created an Developer account for LinkedIn, and have an app with "Advertising API"
I generated a Token with the following permission

```
r_1st_connections_size, r_ads, r_ads_reporting, r_basicprofile, r_organization_admin, r_organization_social, rw_organization_admin, w_member_social, w_organization_social
```

I can get the latest shares of the company using this request :

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:xxxxxx&sharesPerOwner=100
Header :
Linkedin-Version: 202309
```

And the statistics of 1 share using that :

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:xxxxxx&shares[0]=urn:li:share:yyyyyyyy
Header
Linkedin-Version: 202309
```

This works fine for the company account. Now I'd like to obtain the same for a person associated with this company.

According to what I've read in the [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-access-control-by-role?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=http#request-direct-sponsored-content-poster-role), this person must be administrator of the company or maybe granted the permission and the permission : DIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER otherwise we need a special permission r_member_social which is not given to everyone.

When I run :

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationAcls?q=organization&organization=urn:li:organization:xxxxxx&projection=(elements*(*,roleAssignee~(localizedFirstName, localizedLastName), organization~(localizedName)))
```

I obtain that this person is indeed an admin :

```
{
            "organization~": {
                "localizedName": "............."
            },
            "role": "ADMINISTRATOR",
            "organization": "urn:li:organization:xxxxxxxx",
            "roleAssignee": "urn:li:person:zzzzzzzzz",
            "state": "APPROVED",
            "roleAssignee~": {
                "localizedLastName": ".........",
                "localizedFirstName": "...."
            }
        }
```

But, when I try, I'm getting a 403

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:person:yyyyyyyy&sharesPerOwner=100
Header :
Linkedin-Version: 202309
```

403 Not enough permissions to access: POST {endpoint}   Indicates the token used has not been scoped to the correct permissions. Generate a new token with w_organization_social or w_member_social.

But as said earlier, my token had been granted these 2 permissions.

Is it related with "Adverstising API" ?

And for the method organizationalEntityShareStatistics, I understand that only for company shares but I didn't fine anything that may work for a person...

This is my first post, so thank you for the billion of times Stack Overflow helped me in the past 15 years